# Spring Security multiple url ruleset not working together

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an HTTP Spring Security configuration that appears to work when I comment out each individual aspect but it doesn't work when I combine the Spring Security rules together, so I know the problem is not with the `regexMatcher` or the `antMatcher` but with the rules applied in combination.

Here is my Spring Security class:

```
package com.driver.website.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.StaticHeadersWriter;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.frameoptions.XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.security.AccessControlContext;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${widget.headers.xframeoptions.domains.allowed}")
    private String allowedXFrameOptions;

    @Value("${widget.headers.origins.allowed}")
    private String allowedOrigins;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off

        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/myaccount", true).permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

        http.regexMatcher("^((?!(/widget|/assistedSearch)).)*$")
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .regexMatcher("^((?!(/widget|/assistedSearch)).)*$")
                .headers()
                .xssProtection()
                .contentTypeOptions()
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "SAMEORIGIN"));

        http.antMatcher("/widget")
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .antMatcher("/widget")
            .headers()
            .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "ALLOW-FROM " + allowedXFrameOptions));

        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/assistedSearch", "/widget")
            .and()
            .headers()
            .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedOrigins))
            .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST"))
            .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"));

        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

The rules should be...

- For all urls but not /widget and /assistedSearch we should add the SAMEORIGIN X-Frame-Options header
- For the `/widget` endpoint we should add the X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM  header
- For the `/widget` and `/assistedSearch` endpoints we should add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` headers

As I mentioned above if I comment out the `For all urls` ruleset then the other two work in unison, but with the `For all urls` rule uncommented none of the headers appear.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be? How do you add multiple rulesets in Spring Security and override existing rulesets with new ones?

I tried

```
http.antMatcher("/widget")
    .headers()
    .frameOptions()
    .disable()
```

Which again appears to work on it's own but not in combination.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can only add not overwrite rules. Also only the first match will be applied so having multiple rules with the same pattern (or possible matching pattern) will not work as only the first match will win. The rules are also processed in the order they are defined in. As your `/**` is defined first all your other rules are pretty much useless. It is clearly (and in bold if I recall correctly) in the reference guide that `/**` should always be the last one in the chain.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've moved the `everything but not /widget and /assistedSearch` ruleset as the last declaration alas it means that that rule is applied correctly but the /widget and /assistedSearch rules are not.

Now I understand that you've stated they are additive but I technically only added one ruleset to /widget and /assistedSearch so why would it mean that no headers are showing whatsoever?

Comment: So for this question to be downgraded is pretty ridiculous. It's a valid one. I'm specifying mutually exclusive rulesets here. Why offer the power of regular expressions if you can't use mutually exclusive rulesets?

Is anyone aware of the best practise for getting around this issue. Do I have to instead specify interceptors rather than handle it using the DSL?

Comment: YOu cannot have to `antMatchers("/widget")` as then only 1 will apply not both. I meant to say that each matcher pattern is added, once. For `/widget` you have 3 matchers, but only one, probably the first will be applied, not all off them.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. So basically I'll need a static class containing all the rules for '/widget' and a separate ruleset for '/assistedSearch'. Sure it will mean duplicate rules for both but at least then there's separation of concerns and more importantly it will work.  I'll look into that and post my solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You override your previous matchers, see [HttpSecurity.html#antMatcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#antMatcher-java.lang.String-):

> Invoking `antMatcher(String)` will override previous invocations of `mvcMatcher(String)}`, `requestMatchers()`, `antMatcher(String)`, `regexMatcher(String)`, and `requestMatcher(RequestMatcher)`.

and [HttpSecurity.html#regexMatcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#regexMatcher-java.lang.String-):

> Invoking `regexMatcher(String)` will override previous invocations of `mvcMatcher(String)}`, `requestMatchers()`, `antMatcher(String)`, `regexMatcher(String)`, and `requestMatcher(RequestMatcher)`.

If you want more than one configuration of [`HttpSecurity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html), see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity):

> We can configure multiple HttpSecurity instances just as we can have multiple `<http>` blocks. The key is to extend the `WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` multiple times. For example, the following is an example of having a different configuration for URL’s that start with `/api/`.
>
> ```
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
>   @Autowired
>   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { 1
>       auth
>           .inMemoryAuthentication()
>               .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
>               .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
>   }
>
>   @Configuration
>   @Order(1)                                                        2
>   public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>           http
>               .antMatcher("/api/**")                               3
>               .authorizeRequests()
>                   .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
>                   .and()
>               .httpBasic();
>       }
>   }
>
>   @Configuration                                                   4
>   public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>       @Override
>       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>           http
>               .authorizeRequests()
>                   .anyRequest().authenticated()
>                   .and()
>               .formLogin();
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I implemented static classes for each of my rules and then applied them using the correct @Order for each. Once you wrap your head around how Spring Security works behind the scenes then it all makes sense.