# Multiple Spring Security filters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have 2 Spring Security `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configs. I want to filter all requests to path `/filter1` with filter 1, excluding `/filter1/filter2` path. The latter one I want to filter with filter 2. How can I achieve it?

Filter 1 config:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("filter1/filter2/**").permitAll()
            .and()
        .antMatcher("filter1/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .addFilterBefore(filter1, FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
}
```

Filter 2 config:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .antMatcher("filter1/filter2/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .addFilterBefore(filter2, FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
}
```

Comment: Did you try something like "filter1/{^(filter2)}/**" for the second filter allowing only authenticated requests? It basically uses regex for filter2, but I am not sure if this is completely supported (though regexes for path variables are supported).

Comment: Why? What do you want to achieve with multiple security filters?

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to use separate authentications for each url.

Comment: @Him it is not working

Comment: If that is what you want you don't need separate filters for that. Start with an `antMatcher` that matches the path and configure it.

Comment: You are suggesting to combine 2 auth mechanisms in 1 filter?

Comment: @AlvinMahmudov: What is the order of your configuations? The fist one has to be before the second configuration. Show your classes with annotations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603156/spring-security-multiple-http-config-not-working

Answer (score -2):

Just write a single configuration, ordering the urls in the way they should match (ordering is important here!).

Something like the following

```
http
  .csrf().disable()
  .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
  .and()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
   .and()
        .antMatcher("filter1/filter2/**")
        .addFilterBefore(filter2, FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
        .antMatcher("filter1/**")
        .addFilterBefore(filter1, FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
```

Should do that. It will match the most specific one and use that filter chain. Not sure if you need to move the `.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()` to each mapping as well.

Comment: The only thing is, I don't need filter1 to be triggered if filter2 has been triggered.

Comment: It doesn't. It will match the specific one. The first chain that matches will be executed. Hence ordering is important here.

Comment: I just tested and both filters get called. First filter2 then filter1. Even if the path doesn't match. Maybe that is because the filters are defined as spring beans.

Comment: They get called because they are part of the normal filter chain and not just the security filter chain. Add an additional `FilterRegistrationBean` and disable the filter with that (setting the `enabled` property to `false`) to prevent them from being registered in the regular filter chain.

Comment: `
   @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration(SecurityFilter filter2) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter2);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }



    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration2(SecurityFilter filter1) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter1);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }
`
I already have.They are called only when I am accessing filter1 or filter2 paths.

Comment: Weird, that shouldn't happen (AFAIK). Do you have an accidental `@WebFilter` or some additional double instance of the filter? You can enable debug logging for Spring Security and see what is happening in there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183416/discussion-between-alvin-mahmudov-and-m-deinum).

Comment: @M.Deinum I would say, your answer is wrong. See my answer of another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/39465718/5277820. Do you agree?